# Change EJB Classes Dialog - not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can you please tell me where can i find the `Change EJB Classes Dialog` in Intellij IDEA? I read the help, here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ejb-editor.html but i don't have this menu as you can see in the attachemnt.

I would like to create a Remote and Local interface for my EJB.
Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor is available for modules with EJB Facet and META-INF/ejb-jar.xml configuration file defined in EJB facet settings (as noted in the [Web help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editing-module-with-ejb-facet.html)). Check that this requirement is met.

Comment: hello, ok, but if i create an EJB at the New menu, why doesn't it create a ejb-jar.xml file?

Comment: The file may not necessarily be needed. And you can create it in EJB facet settings page.

Comment: i create the ejb-jar.xml file.. but i still can't open the Change EJB Classes Dialog..

Comment: ohh sorry, i had to create a new ejb, and then i can open this menu.. :) thank you!